# Theano installation for Windows, Python 3, 64bit

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-7-x64, theano

Is there a procedure to install Theano for Python 3.4 64bit on Windows 7, manually, without using any of the bundles?

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a step by step tutorial on this today, check it out at:
http://www.islandman93.com/2015/04/tutorial-python-34-theano-and-windows-7.html

Some specifics from my post:

As user2805751 said, you'll need LibPython, Numpy, and Scipy.

You'll also need: MinGW http://mingw-w64.yaxm.org/doku.php/download

Installing Theano with python setup.py install will automatically do the 2to3 conversion.

Answer (score 1):

If the above PR doesn't work, I was able to get the following working for windows 8.1 64 bit (python 2.7.8, but you might try 3.4)

http://pavel.surmenok.com/2014/05/31/installing-theano-with-gpu-on-windows-64-bit/

I needed to also install the LibPython package from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#libpython inorder to fix an ld linker problem.

Comment: What about Python 3.5?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such instruction. There is a new PR with instruction that do not use any bundles, but it is for python2. You can try it, but change python2 for python3:

https://github.com/Theano/Theano/pull/2155